# Facebook app landing page to be index.php

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I am looking to execute some php code on the default landing page for my Facebook app but the app url currently only searches for index.html. Is there a way in which this landing page can be a php page instead of just being an html page?

Update:
How about being able to use: www.example.com/index.php

The configuration under Canvas Page only looks for a URL address with a / at the end of it so does not need a ending page instead just needs a folder.

Maybe I am missing something here.

Thanks.

Comment: I am looking for the right configuration for the canvas URL to be able  to have any landing page that is needed.

Comment: Fix your server so index.php is a default page. `example.com/index.php` and `example.com/` should work the same way (assuming no other `index.*` files interfere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Comment: So how to use just example.com/index.php . That gives an error.

Comment: This works around that error. Try it. Or just fix your server so index.php works, as it should.

Answer (score 1):

As @MozMorris showed, you can include '?' to tell facebook that the url is of a dynamic page and not a static one. But you can always set the order in which the server looks for the file to serve in case it was not specific.

In apache for example you can use the *.htaccess* file for that, as explained in [Set Your Directory Index (Homepage) Using .htaccess](http://davidwalsh.name/directory-index-homepage-htaccess).
That way you can still end the url in the settings with '/' and have it served by *index.php* and not *index.html*.

Comment: You can not do it just with the facebook settings, if it does not end with '/' it must contain '?'. As I wrote, you need to tell the server (your server) with which file to handle requests for the directory, with that you can tell it to use _index.php_ with requests that end with '/' instead of the default _index.html_